# Factor levels dummy variable R

Tags: r, factors, dummy-variable

I am not sure if i should have included levels when I created the factor from a list:

```
random_merge_patients$MedCond <-factor(sort(random_merge_patients[[35]]))
```

Factor example looks like this:

```
[6589] "wt loss  ftt arthritis anemia of chronic disease mild cognitive impairment  hx gout  dehydration prednisone therapy long term med use"
```

If levels were supposed to be selected, what would i choose? Can anyone please clarify as this is confusing to me.

I am going to use this variable to create a dummy variable but even if i get no error message all the values in `$Dementia` are 0s however some should be 1s:

```
random_merge_patients$'MedCond_Dementia'<-ifelse(random_merge_patients$'MedCond' == "dementia",1,0)
```

Comment: Your example is a bit sparse for really helping, but I suggest that given your example `MedCond`, factors are really not appropriate. I suggest keeping them as `character`, and using something like `c$MedCond_Dementia <- grepl("\\bdementia\\b", x$MedCond, ignore.case=TRUE)`, since `...=="dementia"` does not work work as "string contains ...".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be some confusion about what factors are in R. They are a way of representing non-numeric values in a form that allows for traditional statistical models to use them as inputs (e.g. linear modeling). Factors have a fixed set of 'levels' (for the computer), each of which has a 'label' (for the human).  But, R does not intuit what aspects of a character string should be extracted for the labels.

Consider this small case.

```
x = c("wt loss ftt arthritis anemia of chronic disease",
      "sleep loss ftt dementia",
      "wt loss ftt arthritis anemia of chronic disease",
      "wt loss ftt demntia")

f = factor(x)
f
#> [1] wt loss ftt arthritis anemia of chronic disease sleep loss ftt dementia
#> [3] [3] wt loss ftt arthritis anemia of chronic disease wt loss ftt demntia
#> 3 Levels: sleep loss ftt dementia ... wt loss ftt demntia
```

Our original vector had a length of 4 and it contained 3 unique strings.  When we converted it to a factor, R automatically created levels and assigned labels to those levels in alphabetical order (so your `sort` is irrelevant).  Note how the first value in `x` starts with 'wt loss' but the first level starts with `sleep`.  R created 3 levels because there are 3 unique values and accepted the original string as the label.  At this point, our factored vector is really just an integer vector with a way to map labels onto those integers.

```
as.numeric(f)
#> [1] 2 1 2 3
```

Note again how the level (the numeric part) was created in alphabetical order.  So taking a character string and converting it to a factor helps R with automatically creating dummy variables for a linear model but it provides no added benefit if you want to engineer your own features (e.g. creating a 'dementia' column).

For feature engineering in this case, you're much better off looking into regular expressions.  For example, if I wanted to create a vector that coded for weight loss I could do:

```
wt.loss = grepl("w[^ ]*t loss",x)
wt.loss
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

- `grepl` is a logical grep (where `grep` is a searching function) so it will return `TRUE`/`FALSE`
- `"w[^ ]*t loss"` searches for a substring that looks like "w(any non space character repeated 0 or more times)t loss", so it would match "wt loss" or "weight loss".
- `x` specifies the vector to search in.

You can do this for as many features as you want to engineer.  A search for dementia would be `grepl("dementia",x)`.  If there are multiple terms that all mean essentially the same thing you can use | to flag an or condition (e.g. `grepl("osteoperosis|calcium loss in bones",x)`).

Comment: Mark, excellent explanation, thank you so much. This confirmed what had thought of doing and it worked. I can't upvote you because i am a newbie on the site, but thank you.   htn<- grepl("htn", random_merge_patients$'MedCond')
random_merge_patients$'MedCond_HTN'<-ifelse(htn == T,1,0)

Comment: @coding_is_fun You can accept the answer (which also gives you reputation).  Also - you don't need that second `ifelse` statement - binary will automatically convert up to numeric 1/0 if that's what is required.  Try `TRUE+TRUE==2`